# Reading a json object with array

Tags: java, arrays, json

```
{
    "blogURL": "http://crunchify.com",
    "twitter": "http://twitter.com/Crunchify",
    "social": [{
        "id": "1",
        "message": "hi"

    },
    {  
        "id": "2",
        "message": "hello"

     }]
}
```

I am trying to read the above .txt file using the code given below.

```
package com.srishti.space_om;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



public class SPACE_Parse {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, JSONException {
        String jsonData = "";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            String line;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Rachana/workspace/SPACEOM/WebContent/Data/Parse_JSON.txt"));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonData += line + "\n";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // System.out.println("File Content: \n" + jsonData);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        System.out.println("blogURL: " + obj.getString("blogURL"));
        System.out.println("twitter: " + obj.getString("twitter"));

    }
}
```

I am able to read blogURL and twitter but how can I read the first social array i.e, i must be able to read social[0][id] and get 1 and social[1][id] = 2.

Comment: There's most probably a `JSONArray` class that handles the arrays. In your case you'd have an array of `JSONObject` so you'd then do like `((JSONArray)obj.get("social")).get(0).get("id")` (assuming `JSONArray` exists and extends `JSONObject`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

smth like that:

```
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("social");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
    id = row.getInt("id");
    message= row.getString("message");
}
```